# Finding Points of Intersection of 2 circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry for the really basic question but this has been nagging me for a while.

I have two circles:

$ (x-2)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 9$ (--eq1) and

$ (x-1)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 16$ (-- eq2)

Now, I am aware of the general method for solving this and getting the 2 solutions.

When I rewrite the equations and subtract:

$ (x-2)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 9$

$ - ((x-1)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 16$)

---

I get: $ x+2y = 9 $. This is a straight line passing through the 2 solutions. This makes sense.

Now if I do:

eq1*16

eq2*9

and equate the LHS I get: $ 7x^2 + 7y^2 - 46x -78y +190 = 0 $

When I plot this it's a (red) circle which doesn't pass through either solution point. Why doesn't this work? I have a vague intuition of what's going on but shouldn't the 2 solution points still satisfy the equations? I'm not looking for a vague answer for why this is wrong or what the correct solution is. I'd like to know at a deeper (maybe geometric) level for what's going on. Thanks in advance.

I have attached the plots below:

[Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKDxG.jpg)

Edit: $ 7x^2 + 7y^2 - 46x -78y +190 = 0 $ is wrong. Should be $ 7x^2 + 7y^2 - 46x -114y +190 = 0 $. My apologies. Been a long day. Circles intersect. Math makes sense.

Final Edit: Got the solution. Thank you for your responses everyone!:)

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I equate the two LHS of the equations, I get$$7x^2-7y^2-46x-114y+190=0$$

which is not what you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Let's rewrite both ciurcle equations so the RHS is zero: 
$$
(x-2)^2 + (y-3)^2 - 9 = 0
$$
for instance. This has the form $f(x, y) = 0$; let's say the other is $g(x, y) = 0$. When you subtract one from the other, you get
$$
f(x, y) - g(x, y) = 0
$$
Now suppose that $(a, b)$ is a point on the first curve. Then you know that $f(a, b) = 0$; if it's also on the second, then $g(a, b) = 0$. That means that 
$$
f(a, b) - g(a, b) = 0,
$$
hence it lies on the third "curve" (which happens to be a line). So that certainly explains the first computation you did: you created the polynomial 
$f - g$, which *happened* to be linear, and contained the two intersection points. But suppose that instead of subtracting, you'd written down

$$
pf(x, y) + q g(x, y) = 0
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are any two numbers. Then exactly the same analysis would get the same result: any such "linear combination" of the two defining polynomials gets you a new polynomial whose solutions contain any point $(a, b)$ that's a solution of both $f = 0$ and $g = 0$. In short:

> If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials defining (via $f = 0$ and $g = 0$) the
>   curves $C_f$ and $C_g$, and $X \in C_f \cap C_g$, then $X$ also lies
>   on the curve defined by $pf + qg = 0$ for any real numbers $p$ and
>   $q$.

In fact, the word "polynomial" is unnecessary in the theorem above -- they could just be functions.

What you've discovered is that the various curves defined by $pf + qg = 0$ form a 
"pencil of curves", all of which contain the intersection points. If you're willing to restrict to the case $q \ne 0$, you can divide through by $q$ to say that this "pencil of curves" is the same one defined by $\frac{p}{q} f + g = 0$, or, more simply, $\alpha f + g = 0$, as $\alpha$ ranges over all real numbers. You might want to take your curve plot and add to it the curves for $\alpha = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, $ and maybe a few more values (or use a Desmos "slider"!) to see what this "pencil of curves" looks like.

What you've done is snuck up on the very beginnings of some of the ideas of algebraic geometry --- nice work!

Answer (score 0):

If $p.f(x,y)+q.g(x,y)=0$ (eq.0) ,then it's not necessary that $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=0$. I Think your curve is wrong , your circle should pass through your solution. Let take a simple example of straight lines since they are circles of infinite radius $x+y=1$  &  $2.x+y=2$ . we get multiplying eq. 1 by 2 and eq. 1 by 1 , $y=0$ and our solution is (1,0) which passes through $y=0$.

Also in method you use to solve it , you get a straight line which have infinite points on it not your solution , then you intersects it with one of your circles, to get your solution (Note: since one of f or g is zero then  eq.0 becomes zero only when second equation is also zero,which is required condition)
If you intersects your new circle one of circles you will get your desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let:

$$ f=(x-2)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 9 \tag1$$

$$ g=(x-1)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 16 \tag2$$

$f-g=0$ where the circles intersect.

$$f-g=\left(x-2\right)^2\:+\:\left(y-3\right)^2-\left(\left(x-1\right)^2\:+\:\left(y+1\right)^2\right)+\left(-9+16\right)=0$$

Simplifying (not easy!): $$18-2x-8y=0$$

$$x=9-4y \tag3$$
Using either (1) or (2), say we use (2) with this value of $x$, to get:
$$(9-4y-1)^2+(y+1)^2-16=0$$

This has two solutions in $y$:

$$y=2.48904, y=1.15801$$

Using equation (3), with these values for $y$ we get 2 equations to solve for $x$:

$$18-2x-8(2.48904), 18-2x-8(1.15801)$$

Solving the above we get the 2 points of intersection as:

$$P1:(-0.95616
,2.48904), P2:(4.36796,1.15801)$$

[Image for the problem and solution](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gwhnpqgazt).